# Facebook - get informations about shared post

Tags: facebook

I get all posts from my group and I would like to publish it on my website. 
When I shared something post from something fanpage - I can get everything informations about this post:

```
array(2) {
  ["data"]=>
  array(11) {
    [0]=>
    array(13) {
      ["from"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(20) "Franciszek Bonaparte"
        ["id"]=>
        string(15) "120501615004257"
      }
      ["name"]=>
      string(11) "Funny Vines"
      ["description"]=>
      string(25) "lol

Follow - Funny Vines"
      ["full_picture"]=>
      string(144) "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hvthumb-xpf1/v/t15.0-10/12378449_1685955568343914_1258612246_n.jpg?oh=2878b7077fd0b69ed69a6ab1f08119d3&oe=572809E9"
      ["picture"]=>
      string(153) "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hvthumb-xpf1/v/t15.0-10/p130x130/12378449_1685955568343914_1258612246_n.jpg?oh=43ce7f3fa54763e8dbe1fa91125a2fca&oe=57660849"
      ["story"]=>
      string(87) "Franciszek Bonaparte udostÄpniĹ film uĹźytkownika Funny Vines w grupie Testowa Grupa."
      ["source"]=>
      string(224) "https://video.xx.fbcdn.net/hvideo-xpl1/v/t42.1790-2/12744961_750810311722206_1464373469_n.mp4?efg=eyJybHIiOjg1NSwicmxhIjo1MTIsInZlbmNvZGVfdGFnIjoic3ZlX3NkIn0%3D&rl=855&vabr=475&oh=ccf857554a10954d543abd01b599e6b4&oe=56CC1335"
      ["created_time"]=>
      string(24) "2016-02-21T11:16:32+0000"
      ["message"]=>
      string(12) "test message"
      ["id"]=>
      string(33) "1150748191602267_1155126047831148"
      ["likes"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["data"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["summary"]=>
        array(3) {
          ["total_count"]=>
          int(0)
          ["can_like"]=>
          bool(true)
          ["has_liked"]=>
          bool(false)
        }
      }
      ["comments"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["data"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["summary"]=>
        array(3) {
          ["order"]=>
          string(13) "chronological"
          ["total_count"]=>
          int(0)
          ["can_comment"]=>
          bool(false)
        }
      }
      ["attachments"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["data"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          array(4) {
            ["media"]=>
            array(1) {
              ["image"]=>
              array(3) {
                ["height"]=>
                int(640)
                ["src"]=>
                string(144) "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hvthumb-xpf1/v/t15.0-10/12378449_1685955568343914_1258612246_n.jpg?oh=2878b7077fd0b69ed69a6ab1f08119d3&oe=572809E9"
                ["width"]=>
                int(640)
              }
            }
            ["target"]=>
            array(2) {
              ["id"]=>
              string(16) "1271441132885072"
              ["url"]=>
              string(71) "https://www.facebook.com/funnyvinesofficalpage/videos/1271441132885072/"
            }
            ["type"]=>
            string(12) "video_inline"
            ["url"]=>
            string(71) "https://www.facebook.com/funnyvinesofficalpage/videos/1271441132885072/"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Here is screen of this post:

[image]

The problem is when I shared a post from user. I can't get any information about these post:

```
array(2) {
  ["data"]=>
  array(12) {
    [0]=>
    array(6) {
      ["from"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(20) "Franciszek Bonaparte"
        ["id"]=>
        string(15) "120501615004257"
      }
      ["created_time"]=>
      string(24) "2016-02-21T11:20:50+0000"
      ["message"]=>
      string(14) "test message 2"
      ["id"]=>
      string(33) "1150748191602267_1155127894497630"
      ["likes"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["data"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["summary"]=>
        array(3) {
          ["total_count"]=>
          int(0)
          ["can_like"]=>
          bool(true)
          ["has_liked"]=>
          bool(false)
        }
      }
      ["comments"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["data"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["summary"]=>
        array(3) {
          ["order"]=>
          string(13) "chronological"
          ["total_count"]=>
          int(0)
          ["can_comment"]=>
          bool(false)
        }
      }
    }
```

Here is screen of this post:

[image]

Why I can't get informations about author, shared post_id etc.? Here is my code:

```
$response = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/$group_id/feed?fields=from,name,shares,likes.summary(1),comments.summary(1),attachments,description,full_picture,picture,story,source,created_time,message&locale=pl_PL&limit=$limit&access_token=$token");
$array = json_decode($response, true);
```

Thanks for your help!